# How to use $match in aggregate in mongodb for optional parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, match, aggregate, lookup

I m new in mongodb and stucked while using aggregate function.
my query is -> I want to filter database record based on my applied filter in dashboard. 
How can i add filter value using $match operator? it should apply when filter value is present and ignore if not avaliable.

```
if (req.body.filterSet !== undefined) {
        const filterData = req.body.filterSet[0];
        var violation_id = filterData.violation_id;
        var start_notice = filterData.start_notice;
        var end_notice = filterData.end_notice;
        var rc_number = filterData.rc_number;
        var circle = filterData.circle;
        var start_date = filterData.start_date;
        var end_date = filterData.end_date;
        var status = filterData.status;
        var source = filterData.source;
        var sms_status = filterData.sms_status;
        var notice_status = filterData.notice_status;
      }
 Complaint.aggregate([
        { $match : { is_active : { $eq : 1 } } },
        { $match : { id : { $eq : 1103186 } } },
        { $lookup:{ from: 'offences', localField:'offences', foreignField: 'offence_id', as: 'offenceSetail' } },
        { $project: { 'offences.is_active' : 0 } },
        { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$offenceSetail", 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
        { $project: { 'offenceSetail' : 0 } },
        { $lookup: { from: 'registers', localField: 'user_id', foreignField: 'id', as: 'sender'} },
        { $project: { 'registers.is_active' : 0 } },
        { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: ['$sender', 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
        { $project: { 'sender': 0 } },
        { $facet : { length : [ { $count : "total" }], data : [ { $skip: skip }, {$limit: limit } ] } },
      ])
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is...?   Sounds like all you have to do is code up "If filter value in GUI is not null, append an expression to a $match operator."

Comment: what does "...and ignore if not avaliable." mean?  Does this mean if the user added a filter field find documents where the field is null too (thus ignoring the filter value where its not available)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can construct your aggregation stages dynamically like this:

```
const stages = [
    { $lookup:{ from: 'offences', localField:'offences', foreignField: 'offence_id', as: 'offenceSetail' } },
    { $project: { 'offences.is_active' : 0 } },
    { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$offenceSetail", 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
    { $project: { 'offenceSetail' : 0 } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'registers', localField: 'user_id', foreignField: 'id', as: 'sender'} },
    { $project: { 'registers.is_active' : 0 } },
    { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: ['$sender', 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
    { $project: { 'sender': 0 } },
    { $facet : { length : [ { $count : "total" }], data : [ { $skip: skip }, {$limit: limit } ] } }
  ]

if (optional_parameter_exists) {
  stages.unshift(
    { $match: { is_active: { $eq: 1 } } },
    { $match: { id: { $eq: 1103186 } } }
  );
}

Complaint.aggregate(stages);
```

Comment: Its works like a champ. Thanks Suleyman.
One more help please.
----------------------------
var violation_id = 101;

 if(violation_id != null && violation_id != ''){
        console.log(violation_id);
      stages.unshift(
        { $match : { id: { $eq: violation_id } } }
      )
      } //did not get record

 if(violation_id != null && violation_id != ''){
        console.log(violation_id);
      stages.unshift(
        { $match : { id: { $eq: 1103186 } } }
      )
      } record found. 
why I am not getting record for dynamic value? Please help.

Comment: @VickyKumar I am happy that it helped you,  please consider this as answer.
About your new question, it would be better if you can ask a new question, because mixing other questions in a question is not motivated in stackoverflow, and it is difficult to answer in comments, I hope you understand.